# Is there a tool or something that can "listen" to javascript functions called on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a tool, or something like this for intercepting JavaScript functions when they're called on a webpage, for example let's say I'm on a webpage and I press on Up Arrow key which has an event attached to it that calls a method to change a div  color to red.. Is there any tools which can log me the called function's name while I pressed the up arrow ?

Comment: Most modern browsers come with developer tools built in. You can use these to assess what is happening, with functions, variables, events, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Firebug for this: https://getfirebug.com/

This is a very versatile Firefox plugin, used for development and *investigation* :-)

You can then use the "Break on next" function in the "Script"-panel:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Break_On_Next

This will show you the executing code every time a piece of javascript code is activated.

The rest of Firebug's function should also allow you to find out exactly what you need.

Comment: Chrome and newer versions of IE have this functionality built in.

Comment: Firefox also has this built in: Menu > Web Developer > Toggle Tools. Be sure to check out the '3D view'-function, fancy as fck! Still prefer Firebug though!

Comment: This no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a debugger tool similar to Firebug and the common shortcut is the F12 key:

- IE : F12
- Chrome: F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I
- Opera: Ctrl + Shift + I
- Firebug: F12

In most of them you can also use "breakpoint" in your javascript code on-fly and you also can write in the javascript console directly by writing in your javascript code something like:  `console.log("hello")`.

You can also interact directly with the Dom or loaded javasript objects by calling them in the tab "console" of this kind of tools.

These kind of developper tool can also help you to interact on the CSS.